# Ophrah in both Joshua 18 and Judges

Tags: judges, joshua

In Judges 6:11 (NASB)

> Then the angel of the Lord came and sat under the oak that was in **Ophrah**, which belonged to Joash the Abiezrite, as his son Gideon was beating out wheat in the wine press in order to save it from the Midianites.

and Judges 8:27 (NASB)

> Gideon made it into an ephod, and placed it in his city, **Ophrah**; but all Israel committed infidelity with it there, and it became a snare to Gideon and his household.

we read of Gideon's hometown - Ophrah. Also, in Joshua 18:23 (NASB)

> Avvim, Parah, and **Ophrah**,

Is the Ophrah from Judges the same from Joshua?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two towns called "Ophrah":

- A Bejaminite town as per Josh 18:23
- A town in Manasseh as per Judges 6:11, 15, 24, 8:27, 32.  This town in both sets of references is closely associated with Gideon.

Note that there are several clues that Judges 6:11, 15, 24, 8:27, 32 all describe "Ophrah" as Gideon's city in Manasseh confirming that they refer to the same place.  Note Matthew Poole's comments:

> The case seems to be this, Gideon having by God’s command erected an
> altar in his own city, Ophrah, Judges 6:26, for an extraordinary time
> and occasion.

Comment: From [here](https://biblehub.com/commentaries/judges/6-11.htm), according to Matthew Poole's Commentary, Barnes' Notes on the Bible, Benson Commentary and Ellicott's Commentary for English Readers, they weren't the same location

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 - they all agree that the other "Ophrah" was in Benjamin as listed above.  So the two in Judges 6 & 8 are the same as stated by these same commentators.

Comment: «This Ophrah was in Western Manasseh. There was another in Benjamin»

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 - correct - we are discussing only the one in Manasseh - Gideon's hometown.

Comment: I'm not following... The question asks about Joshua and Judges. Are you saying that in both cases (Judges vs Joshua) is the same "Ophrah"?

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 - NO.  Both Ophrah's in Judges are the same place, Manasseh.  However, the one in Joshua is in Benjamin.  See the answer above.